# Can you install packages in R without imports or dependencies?

Tags: r, qdap, tidytext

I work on a computer that doesn't have internet access.  I download all of my R packages and install them from .zip files.  One issue, however, is that when I install a package, it will require other packages because I load them into the library.

For example, I downloaded QDAP, and it says something along the lines of, "can't load until you download and install rJava". This goes on multiple times with several different packages.  Is there anyway to avoid this?  I don't need the "wordcloud package, but it's requiring that I install it before I can even use QDAP.